# guardar en variables valores de grabc

Tags: linux, bash, shell

¿Cómo puedo guardar en variables los valores RGB de grabc?

```
grabc -rgb
```

o de este otro código:

```
xwd -root -silent | convert xwd:- -depth 8 -crop "1x1+$X+$Y" txt:- | grep -om1 '#\w\+'
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Además, para lo de lcontrol abriría una nueva pregunta porque no tiene nada que ver con guardar un valor en una variable.

Comment: ¿Sabes cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para guardar variables en bash puedes poner tu comando entre las siguientes comillas ``` `` ```

Por ejemplo:

```
VAR=`COMANDO`
```

Así pues para el segundo comando probablemente estés buscando algo así:

```
VAR=`xwd -root -silent | convert xwd:- -depth 8 -crop "1x1+$X+$Y" txt:- | grep -om1 '#\w\+'`
```

El primero es un poco diferente, ya que atendiendo a la [documentación](https://github.com/muquit/grabc), parece que el parámetro `-rgb` hace que la utlidad escriba por STDERR en lugar de STDOUT, así que necesitarás redirigir la salida para poder guadar el contenido en la variable:

```
VAR=`grabc -rgb 2>&1`
```

Comment: Agradecido con usted

Comment: Es mucho mejor usar `var=$(comando)`, pues permite anidar.